# How to pass AJAX POST data to jQUery ColorBox?

Tags: jquery, post, colorbox

I have gone through various threads on this but I could not get a satisfactory solution to pass form data using POST method to jQuery colorbox plug-in while iframe attribute is set to true. I'm able to pass data using query string but my requirement is pass data using POST method from the linked window and capture it in colorbox and take further action. I tried it in various ways and following is one of the ways:

```
$.colorbox({
     closeButton:true, 
     open:true, 
     iframe:true, 
     href:"/python/try_python.php", 
     type:"POST", 
     data:{'code[]':[src]}, 
     opacity:.45, 
     width:"960", height:"600"
});
```

I know there are plenty of jQuery legends who can suggest a way around. Kindly help.

Regards
Mohtashim

Comment: [What does your jquery code look like? What's wrong with your code?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry Rawgulmuffins, Now I updated my question itself. Hope it gives some clue. I have tried it in various ways but post method does not work.

Comment: No further comment from anybody????

Answer (score 1):

I could not success in posting my content using POST method but I found a workaround where did the following:

(a) Saved my content in a hidden ...
(b) Access this content from the iframe window upon successful load using the following:

```
var code = window.parent.$("#source");
```

and this is what I wanted to have....May be it will help many others. If you find a solution to pass direct content using post method kindly share.